# adwords script get metrics.search_rank_lost_impression_share > 0 for keywords

Tags: google-ads-api

first question ) is ist possible to get metrics.search_rank_lost_impression_share > 0 for keywords ?

um using for campaigns

AdsApp.campaigns().withCondition("Status = ENABLED").withCondition("metrics.search_rank_lost_impression_share > 0").forDateRange("YESTERDAY").get();

second question)

how can i make a or condition between two Conditions ?

i want to get all campaigns where  metrics.search_rank_lost_impression_share > 0 or metrics.search_rank_lost_absolute_top_impression_share > 0

i tried everything i